# Replacing href click behavior with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As an exercise, I'm trying to make my links in the navbar contract the content div, load the page in #content using ajaxpage() and then slide it back down. I'm using the following:

**EDIT:** I realized that I probably needed everything in a callback function, so I fixed that. The call still isn't working, though.

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("a.link").click(function() { 
    //...
    return false;
});
  $("#navbar a").click(function(){
    $("#content").slideUp(500,function(){
        var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
        ajaxpage(a_href, 'content');
        $("#content").slideDown(500);
        });
  });
});
```

With the link being:

```
<a class="link" href="home.php">Home</a>
```

When I test it, the content div correctly slides up, but then it stays there and nothing else happens. What did I do wrong here?

**EDIT:** After some debugging, it seems like this is the culprit:

```
var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
```

When I declare that variable and send it through an alert(), it says "undefined". I'm guessing I'm not grabbing the attribute properly, so this is where it's hanging up! How would I properly go about grabbing the href attribute of the link that you click?

Comment: Your AJAX call is probably failing, post code for `ajaxpage` function. I can also tell you the call is probably asynchronous, so your `slideDown` should be in the AJAX callback.

Comment: Yep, I was just fixing that! The ajax call works fine, since I can use it in a href without fail: href="javascript:ajaxpage('home.php', 'content')"

Comment: Can you please share the html in a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you really want is to capture the href of the element that was clicked.

```
$("#navbar a").click(function(){
    var a_href = $(this).prop('href');
    $("#content").slideUp(500,function(){
        ajaxpage(a_href, 'content');
        $("#content").slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

But just so we're clear, before the ajax call returns any data, the `$('#content').slideDown(500)`; is going to fire off. You need to add a callback to `ajaxpage` to accept as the success function of the `$.ajax()` so you can determine when to `slideDown()`.

Answer (score 0):

when you determine href you should after on click using `attr()`.

```
$("#navbar a").click(function(){
    var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#content").slideUp(500,function(){
        ajaxpage(a_href, 'content');
        $("#content").slideDown(500);
        });
  });
```